# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails even there is onDelete Cascade and onUpdate cascade?

Tags: laravel

**Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails**

```
users Table
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->string('name');
  $table->string('email')->unique();
  $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
  $table->string('password');
  $table->rememberToken();
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

```
cv table

 Schema::create('cvs', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
  $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
  $table->string('name')->nullable();
  $table->string('contact')->nullable();
  $table->string('contact2')->nullable();
  $table->string('gender')->nullable();
  $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
  $table->string('paddress')->nullable();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason can be:

- your migration of CSV is before Users.
  Take a look migration names (and dates). It should be:

  2019_02_01_101010_create_users_table.php

  2019_02_02_101010_create_csv_table.php (look, date is 2019_02_02)

Then fire `php artisan:migrate`

Be sure that in other migrations you have proper dates. Migration can not work if one table want relation with table that was not created yet.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you need to migrate the `users` table first, then the `cvs`
to do that:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/selected
```

if you have run migration before you need to migrate

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
```

then run

```
php artisan migrate
```

It'll automatically migrate all the rest of the tables for you

Hope this helps